# Aptana on Ecplise Open PHP Element window not working with sftp connection

Tags: eclipse, aptana, sftp, aptana3

I've started a new Web Project but both the "Open PHP Element" and the "Open Resource" windows are not working. They open but they show no files... I guess its because I'm using an sftp connection for the project...

I've tried to create a local project and the window works... How can I make these two windows work with sftp connection?

Thank, Joaogl.